# facing problem on appending html form to my Angular based project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using Angular

- where I have a Add button which appends HTML on clicking it again
  again .
- when I click add button **problem is**  appended content dosen't show textbox  , dropdown , It jut display field name as text .

I am sharing my code

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  htmlToAdd : any ;
  newHtml : any 
  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}
  add(){
     this.htmlToAdd = `  <form action="/action_page.php">
                  First name:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
                  <br>
                   Last name:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
                  <br><br>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                  </form> `
      }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="one" [innerHtml]="htmlToAdd"></div> 
<button (click)='add()'> Add </button>
<div [innerHtml]='newHtml'></div>
```

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the error or the details of the problem you're facing?

Comment: i am not getting any syntex error as of now  but problem is html appends just once to inner html but it is not appending again and again on every click

Comment: Instead of assigning everytime do use += that will append into string instead of reassigning. `this.htmlToAdd +=`

Answer (score 1):

This would make a lot more sense using something like ngFor.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of array">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
         <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
    </ng-container>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<button (click)="add()"></button>
```

Then something like this in your TS i am sure there are better ways but you get the idea.

**TS**

```
array = [];

add() {    
    this.array.push(this.array.length + 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is: `htmlToAdd` is not getting appended. It get's re-initialized every time, when `add()` method is invoked.

Try with the below change:

**TS**

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  htmlToAdd = '';

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  add() {
    this.htmlToAdd = `${this.htmlToAdd}<form action="/action_page.php">
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
      <br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> `;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="one" [innerHtml]="htmlToAdd"></div> 
<button (click)='add()'> Add </button>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpm4px

Hope this helps you!

> **This is not the proper way of implementing dynamic field configuration**

By using **form arrays** in **reactive forms**, you achieve this in a better way.
You can read more about angular forms and operations here: 
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays

Comment: thanks @Jins , can you see in stackblitz why form fields are not appearingon append

Comment: @Anurag I'm not clear what you're intending to do. Can you elaborate please?